# Compose TextField SupportingText Cut Off on Long Text Value

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-compose-textfield

I'm making a form screen with Compose, and I've made a text box using an `OutlinedTextField` with an exact height set. The text box has supporting text that says "Optional", and if I enter too many lines in the box, the supporting text gets cut off/obscured completely. It looks like the `OutlinedTextField` pushes the supporting text out of the way to make room for the value when the height is set to an exact amount. If I change the dimensions to only set a minimum height, the `OutlinedTextField` will expand as more text is entered, and the supporting text will stay visible, but I don't want that.

How it looks before any text or only a small amount of text is entered:

**Empty TextField**
[image]

How it looks after lots of text is entered or new lines are added:

**Cut off supporting text**
[image]

I've also tried adding a vertical scroll to the `OutlinedTextField`, but that makes it extend passed its specified height, so I don't want that either. Is there a way I can modify my `OutlinedTextField` so that the supporting text is always visible when using an exact height?

Text box implementation:

```
var text by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf("") }

OutlinedTextField(
    value = text,
    onValueChange = {
        text = it
        onValueChangeAction(it)
    },
    label = { Text(label) },
    keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(
        capitalization = KeyboardCapitalization.Sentences
    ),
    supportingText = { Text(text = "Optional") },
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .height(200.dp)
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was reproducible in material 3 - version `1.1.0-alpha07`.
It is not reproducible anymore in the new version.

Upgrade your dependency version to this or higher,

```
androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.2.0-alpha02
```

Note, this is the current latest version and it works.
It may have been fixed in some in between versions as well.